# Displaying Angular 4 email validation text in paragraph

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

Im using the Angular 4 built in email input validator. It works, but I can only see the information in the small popup. Is it possible to display it in paragraph, below the input?

[image]

My input code:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" [(ngModel)]="eMail" email pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" required>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

In your HTML :

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" formControlName="email" required>
        <div [hidden]="!(myForm.controls.email?.dirty && myForm.controls.email?.invalid)">
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
 [hidden]="!myForm.controls.email?.errors?.required">This field is required</small>
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
 [hidden]="!myForm.controls.email?.errors?.pattern">Wrong format error message</small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in your app.component.ts file :

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
    ...
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(Regex.EMAIL))
});
```

For your patterns :

```
export class Regex {
    public static EMAIL = '^[a-z0-9]+(\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,15})$';
    ...
}
```